# .htaccess throws 404

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, http-status-code-404

I have a .htaccess with Rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^admin/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule !\.(gif|jpg|png|css|js|ico|htc|txt|swf|pdf)$ index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
#AddHandler php5-script .php
Options -Indexes
```

Basicly, it sends all files to index.php except the /admin/ folder and the file types above. It works just fine, but i needed to protect the /admin/ folder with .htaccess:

```
AuthName "Area Admin"
AuthUserFile "/path/to/folder/passwd/"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

When i protect the folder, /admin/ stops working and starts throwing 404. If i remove it it works just fine.

Comment: When you say protect?  Do you mean you want a username and password but still give? access?

Answer (score 0):

Add the .htaccess in the admin folder root with your permissions.  This way it will exclude itself from your main .htaccess file and ask for credentials if you were to hit that folder.

Comment: When i say add the .htaccess, i mean add a second .htaccess in your root and remove the file permissions your trying to add to the main one, and add them to the admin .htaccess.  Hope that makes sense.